# sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier deprecated in iOS 6, alternatives?

Tags: ios

Does anyone know the new method to use instead of `sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier`, which is deprecated in iOS 6?

Answer (score 1):

There is not other method. You can use the *frame* property, it gives you the ad view size as well.

```
CGSize adSize = adView.frame.size;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `bounds` property -

```
CGSize myBannerSize = myBanner.bounds.size;
```

Apple didn't replace `sizeFromBannerContextSizeIdentifier` - you'll need to use the `bounds`.